# Photoshop layers icon missing

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, workspace

I'm new to photoshop, and in my layers panel the icons that show you what your layer looks like disappeared, they just show a brush instead:

[image]

I don't know how to get it back. I tried resetting my workspace but that didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on the menu dropdown (top right) and select **Panel Options**

Change **Thumbnail Size** from **None** to your desired size.

[image: [GIF]

Comment: So simple, but I never would have figured it out. Thanks!